# Pytest fails due to VTK import error when called by gitci, but not when called directly

Tags: python, conda, gitlab-ci, vtk, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a windows 10 machine running a gitlab runner version 13.4.1. Our repo has been configured with a gitlab-ci yml file that builds a new conda environment (including vtk version 8.1.0) and then runs a pytest unit tests in that environment.

Until a few days ago, this was working fine. Recently all our pipelines have been receiving some version of the same error that:

```
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\path\to\test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\vtk\vtkCommonCore.py:5: in <module>
    from .vtkCommonCorePython import *
E   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
C:\path\to\virtualenv\gitci-env\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Tests\test.py:4: in <module>
    import vtk
C:\path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\vtk\__init__.py:7: in <module>
    from .vtkCommonCore import *
C:\path\to\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\vtk\vtkCommonCore.py:9: in <module>
    from vtkCommonCorePython import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkCommonCorePython'
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
ERROR Tests\test.py
```

Other points worth noting:

- This error does not occur if the virtual environment is invoked in a powershell and the unit tests run there. It can only be replicate through a gitlab-ci pipeline.
- If a simple assert True unit test is run it will pass through gitlab-ci. If it is modified to import vtk, it will fail
- Creating a named environment on the server and updating the yml file to use that existing environment rather than making a fresh one does not resolve the behaviour.
- Machine restart didn't resolve the issue

Does anyone have any insight on why this might happen or how to resolve it?

Comment: That is most likely a path issue. The virtual environment configures this for you. I will strongly recommend that you run everything inside virtual environment and store a recipe to establish a working virtual environment. If you insist on not using a virtualenv, check your path for the missing DLLs

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. My understanding was that conda acts as a virtual environment with the additional feature that it is language agnostic and supports other languages outside of python (https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-conda-environments-bc6180fc533).  For my application, it is a requirement that we use conda to manage the python environment.

Do you have any thoughts on how to troubleshoot the path used within a conda environment?

Comment: I was able to work around this issue by taking an old conda environment I had previously made and updating gitlab-ci to use that environment. It is worth noting that gitlab-ci still will fail if it creates a fresh environment OR if I make a new named environment